# Is every + leg correct?

Tags: each-every

Some books I have read explains that "every" isn't used for **two things** or **people**. One of the examples I took from Oxford Grammar:

> She can write with each hand (**but not** ... every hand).

I wonder if this rule is also applied in animals. Suppose, I wanted to make a descriptive text about centipedes. Based on the rule above, it shouldn't be a problem if I wrote like this:

> Every leg of a centipede has four segments.

Comment: Why do you think the rule would apply to animals that have _more_ than two legs?

Comment: @KateBunting it's just a guess. Sorry. I hope someone can confirm.

Comment: The point I was making is that most animals have four legs, or more in the case of insects and other arthropods such as centipedes, so a grammatical rule about *two* things isn't relevant here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably could use either “every” or “each” for your example. To me,

> *Each* leg of a centipede has four segments.

sounds a bit more natural and idiomatic. It may be because of the association between the word “each” and the phrase “each and every,” which places an emphasis on each individual object (note how I used “each” in this sentence as well— it highlights the importance of the object as an *individual*).